# Unit test mock interface and need convert original interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have a problem in C# unit test. When I test some methods, They are need to convert original interface. like this:

```
_stubInterface1 = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Interface1>();
...
var someData = (Interface1)_stubInterface1;
```

Then CLR throw exception. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is the exception exactly?

Comment: like this: Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IRepositoryProxyac1ff7ff97894e9295744bf02790b123' to type 'DEST.Base'.

Comment: Is that RhinoMocks? I've added the appropriate tag

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any good idea? I don't know how to  generateMock interface and can be revert it...

Comment: Yes, that is RhinoMocks 3.6.1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exception doesn't occur on any of those 2 lines you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. My question has error. I mean that:

```
_stubInterface1 = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Interface1>();
...
var someData = (Interface2)_stubInterface2;
```

solution:

```
_stubInterface1 = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Interface1,Interface2>();
...
var someData = (Interface2)_stubInterface2;
```

Thanks all reply and all guys.